# java 2d array when size is not known

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to create and order an array of objects, problem is the objects cannot be ordered by themselves. Instead they are ordered based off an integer value. So I thought of using a 2d array.

```
 Object[][] array = new Object[][]
```

That way I can store in the array the

```
 [integer to order the objects][object]
```

But the problem is I don't know how many objects there will be that need to be ordered, so, do I need to use an Arraylist instead?

Either way, is it possible to use a collection.sort command, and how can I possible get an array to behave as described?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to forget about raw arrays and start thinking in terms of the Java Collections Framework.

For sorting use a `TreeMap<Integer, Object>`. After you've `put` all your objects in, you can use `values()` to get the objects in proper order.

Using the map you have also eliminated all problems of size determination.

Comment: Doh - much better answer than my now-deleted one :)

Comment: Actually having some problems, to clarify, the integer is a value I am inputting, which isn't always unique, is it still possible to use that value to order the tree?

Comment: No, in that case your situation is quite a bit more complicated and actually @JonSkeet's answer will probably be the simplest approach. Jon, if you're reading this, now I should delete my answer and you undelete yours!

Comment: Actually just solved it, it would seem that the positioning inside some for-loops may have been overriding the order. Moving it outside the loop just fixed it...so happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList` with `Comparator interface` to order them.

Moreover **TreeMap is a Sorted Map** which will sort your Object on the basis of Integer value as you mention them as the Key to the Values.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Object>

Integer - Key

Object  - Value
```

You **don't need to initialize the Collections** like u need to do with Arrays.... So thats another probs taken care off....